# stop unexpectedly my app when peress botton in emulator/android

Tags: android

My code compiles and run on emulator but when button is pressed it stops and shows the message `"the application stopped on unexpectedly"`. I've searched a lot and read some related posts but they didn't help. Could you help me? I got the following message: `"Fatal Exception:main"message
main XML file`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testing.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my activity is

```
package com.example.testing;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    double latituden;
    double longtituden;
    double [][] matrix_a = {{33.977517,51.456953},
                            {33.980738,51.426285},
                            {33.989817,51.433273},
                            {33.994729,51.437565},
                            {33.995928,51.447210},
                            {33.992708,51.446357},
                            {33.984604,51.436315},
                            {33.974430,51.433501},
                            {33.983399,51.445335},
                            {33.978474,51.466491}   
                  };{
    for (int i=0;i<matrix_a.length;i++)
    {
           latituden=i;
        for (int j=0;j<matrix_a.length;j++){
            longtituden=j;
        }}};

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "welcome to this app"  ,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                 if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        for (int i=0;i<matrix_a.length;i++)
        {

            for (int j=0;j<matrix_a.length;j++){ 
                Distclass distclass= new Distclass(); 

                double[] distance = distclass.Calculate(gps.getLatitude(),gps.getLongitude(),latituden,longtituden);

                Arrays.sort(distance); 
               double  min = distance[0];
            System.out.println(min);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "min distance from your location is - \nmin: " + min, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    };
}});}}
```

Comment: Did you check the log? Add it to your question...

Comment: The formatting is very poor, which certainly wont help.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why this might crash and with the details you provided I can think of several like:

1. Have you declared your Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`. All Activities in your application have to be declared there, inside the `<application></application>` tag like this

   ```
   <application
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
2. What is GPSTracker? Is it imported from somewhere? The crash might be related to that class.
3. Check your logcat. A crash should be visible there. The Logcat feature can be accessed from Android Studio. For more on that, check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)

Comment: very thanks from your answer. i check  your reasons . The first reason is not difficult but there is a warning in the manifest file.

Comment: ." No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document." GPSTracker is one class that declared current user location. my app writing in eclipse  environment and LogCat is empty but before displey this error " FATAL Exception Main"

Comment: .and in  rerun console display this error " [2016-07-19 10:50:26 - testing] ------------------------------
[2016-07-19 10:50:26 - testing] Android Launch!
[2016-07-19 10:50:26 - testing] adb is running normally.
[2016-07-19 10:50:26 - testing] Performing com.example.testing.MainActivity activity launch

Comment: [2016-07-19 10:50:26 - testing] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2016-07-19 10:50:45 - testing] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'v'

Comment: [2016-07-19 10:50:46 - Emulator] WARNING: userdata image already in use, changes will not persist!
[2016-07-19 10:50:46 - Emulator] WARNING: cache image already in use, changes will not persist!
[2016-07-19 10:50:46 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\pariya\.android\avd\v.avd/sdcard.img
[2016-07-19 10:50:46 - Emulator] ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Users\pariya\.android\avd\v.avd/snapshots.img". can you help me?thanks.

Comment: Hello @VajiheIllchi you are not looking at the right logcat. Open DDMS tool and check the error logs in there. To do that,  Click Window > Open Perspective > Other... > DDMS. Let us know what you find in the DDMS error part (The error should start with FATAL EXCEPTION: ... message)

Comment: Hi.in logcat this massage is show"androidrun:FATAL EXCEPTION:main" and in and in console DDMS show this massage "[2016-07-21 06:36:19 - DDMS] device offline
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:774)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:396)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:347)

Comment: at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:610)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.SysinfoPanel$1.run(SysinfoPanel.java:209)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" this can help you to declared my problem?

Comment: sorry. there are this error report on logcat from DDMS .

Comment: 07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at java.util.DualPivotQuicksort.sort(DualPivotQuicksort.java:1892)

Comment: 07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1604)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at com.example.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)

Comment: 07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: 07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: 07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-16 17:13:26.940: E/AndroidRuntime(1046):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 17:28:51.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 17:28:51.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): java.lang.NullPointerException
)

Comment: 07-16 17:28:51.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):  at java.util.DualPivotQuicksort.sort(DualPivotQuicksort.java:1892)
07-16 17:28:51.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1604)
07-16 17:28:51.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):  at com.example.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
07-16 17:28:51.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-16 17:28:51.975: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816

Comment: and ... that i remo beacuse is very long this error related to 2 run of program.you can help me? sorry to bad format and very very thanks from your help.

Comment: @VajiheIllchi just remove these lines`Arrays.sort(distance);  double  min = distance[0];
            System.out.println(min);` and let me know if the crash is still on

Comment: Hi. i remove related line but problem not solve and when press on button closed my app. and DDMS show bellow message in logcat:

Comment: 07-16 17:28:52.241: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.example.testing/.MainActivity
07-16 17:28:53.704: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45fd1a38 com.example.testing/.MainActivity}
07-16 17:29:05.435: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{45fd1a38 com.example.testing/.MainActivity}
07-16 17:31:40.576: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: 07-16 17:33:52.433: I/Process(1054): Sending signal. PID: 1054 SIG: 9
07-16 17:33:52.433: I/ActivityManager(59): Process com.example.testing (pid 1054) has died.
07-16 17:33:52.565: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{460db860 com.example.testing/com.example.testing.MainActivity paused=false}
07-16 17:33:52.565: W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1054 uid 10047
07-16 17:33:54.567: W/GpsLocationProvider(59): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000

Comment: 07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rblocation/com.example.rblocation.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

Comment: 07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

Comment: 07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at com.example.rblocation.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:83)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

Comment: 07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-16 20:22:34.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1170):  ... 11 more

Comment: 07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at java.util.DualPivotQuicksort.sort(DualPivotQuicksort.java:1892)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1604)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at com.example.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)

Comment: 07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

Comment: 07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-16 18:15:22.057: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 18:15:22.194: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.example.testing/.MainActivity
07-16 18:15:22.859: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45f818d0 com.example.testing/.MainActivity}

Comment: 07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at java.util.DualPivotQuicksort.sort(DualPivotQuicksort.java:1892)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1604)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at com.example.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)

Comment: 07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

Comment: 07-16 22:33:43.886: E/AndroidRuntime(1253):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: massage is very long and send by commend is very difficult and i send a few then for you. i think problem is very big . can you help me? thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a `NullPointerException` in `MainActivity` at line 87.
It is really hard for me to see what's on that line.
The `NullPointerException` is thrown from `DualPivotQuicksort.java`, and it is related to some sort of `Arrays.sort()` method call.
It seems you're trying to sort a null array.

My advice: remove all lines in `onClick()` and make sure it works. After that, add lines one by one and see which one causes the error and let me know.

Comment: hi. i think problem related to avd . because icon avd no access in my eclipse and with run another problem too Contains  this error and emulator is very slow.I can mail or telegram account you have?

Comment: Try to run it on a device instead maybe. The emulator is slow because emulation speed delays. You can also try https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: i install youwaive and run my app. very very thanks because your helps and your answers.Good luck.

Comment: If you like my answer, please give it a +1. If it responded to your question, set it as approved answer. Thank you and good luck